# [Finding the value of x given 2 points and product of those two points]

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

The question in the lecture slide is if Point 1 (x,0) Point (2,5) and Point1Point2 = 5√2, find x

What I did was apply the distance formula

d = √(x2-x1)²+(y2-y1)²
where 5√2 is d and use the following points to the formula

Got the answer of x = 7-5√2.

There is no answer given in the PowerPoint and I'm not confident with the way I solve it so I am here asking for guidance or clues

Answer (score 1):

$$(5\sqrt{2})^2=(x-2)^2+(5)^2$$
$$(x-2)^2=25$$
$$x=2\pm5=-3 \text{ or } 7$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this may I know the reason why we did not expand (x-2)^2 like x^2-4x+2?

Comment: I guess you want to expand and apply the quadratic formula. The quadratic formula is actually derived from rearranging $ax^2+bx+c=0$ to $(x-b/2a)^2=b^2/4a^2 - c/a$, which implies the latter is easier to solve. We can just take the square root of each sides.